# Electrelet Microphone in Amplifier Circuit

Tags: amplifier, condenser-microphone

I am trying to build this circuit with the only difference in my version being 9 volts instead of 12. For my Microphone I used a Electret condenser microphone from [here.](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/mike-79/electret-microphone/1.html)[image]

It says it runs on 2.2vdc so I put a 330k resistor is series with the microphone. My problem is that the only noise i get to the headphones is if I tap on the microphone. If I blow on it or talk into it nothing comes through to the headphones. I tried it with and without the resistor with a 1m and 1k resistor and checked the polarity of the microphone. Any help appreciated. If needed this [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Ultra-Sensitive-Spy-Ear/?&sort=ACTIVE&limit=40&offset=40#DISCUSS) is to the tutorial.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say "I put a 330k resistor is series with the microphone."  Where, exactly, is the resistor?

Comment: It is right between the mic and gnd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electret microphones need a positive pull up resistor. Forget the pot and 330k and try a 4k7 directly to +9V. The device in the link doesn't have a data sheet but reading between the lines you would probably power it from 5V using a 2k2 resistor and the output would naturally settle to about 2.2V.

Running it from 9V using a 4k7 should be OK but please do measure the voltage on the mic when the 4k7 is connected in case there are any problems.

Background info - Never buy any electrical part that doesn't have a data sheet.

Comment: Do you mean by 4k7 a 4.7 k resistor. Also is there a difference between pullup and regular resistors? I know that is a lot of questions but I really appreciate answer and will vote it up once my questions are answered. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes 4.7 k ohms. Pull up is shorthand for connect something to Vcc.

Comment: I did not have a 4.7k so I used a 5.6k and also tried a 10k. Both of them worked but now I have another problem. The microphone only picks up sounds that are less that 3 inches away from it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Double check your LM386 circuit and if you could post a diagram that shows more detail of pin numbers. I guess you are basing the design on this: http://hackaweek.com/hacks/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/LM386ampschematicfinal1.jpg

Comment: Yes I am. Also one thing I just noticed, I haven't been paying attention to the type of cap(ceramic vs. electrolyte, etc). That is the correct pin out, what you posted. I have changed c1 in the original diagram to a 10uf for better gain and that hasn't helped that much.